# What would be causing this? Sharepoint caching

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caching, sharepoint-2007

I implemented this code from  [this](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2008/09/23/sharepoint-caching-and-cachedependency.aspx)  tutorial.

I am caching a SPItem and I noticed I ran into this problem. I stick in the SPItem and take it right away out.

The SPItem that I am getting from the cache is fine and useable. However after like a few times of grabbing this item out all of a sudden every single property throws an "null reference exception".

What would cause properties to throw "Null reference exceptions". I mean these are even like string properties where I would not expect to see such an exception.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. 
The cached item is removed from cache at that time that you specify in `absoluteExpiration` parameter.
If you specified `slidingExpiration` the object will expire and removed from the cache as many minutes after it was last accessed as you specified in the Insert or Add method call.

Which one to use when? Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77.aspx).
So tweak values of these parameters.

Always do null checks while retrieving objects from cache and accordingly update/refresh stale cache.

Comment: @ukhardy - I set  System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration should that not stop it? If I read the tutorial right I thought it was designed in away to only let go of the cache when a file or something changes.

Comment: check **if (details.LastModified < oFile.TimeLastModified)** is true when you get a null.

Comment: @ukhardy  where is details and OFile coming from?

Comment: oFile represents SharePoint File **SPFile oFile = oSite.RootWeb.GetFile(sKey);**. It's details are coming from SharePoint, sKey is the File Url that you passed to SPFileCacheDependency constructor in your calling code

Comment: @ukhardy  - What is oSite coming from?

Comment: Ah, I see your point, well you mentioned reading the aforesaid tutorial; this code (I pasted above) is from your referenced tutorial.

Comment: @ukhardy  - Ya I been looking more into their code and see this oSite. So I should do the check there?

Comment: ya that's a good place to ckeck that when you retrieve the object from cache and get null, indeed it has been modified. Next thing to look at is the modifications. And if there has been a modification, then cache needs refreshing - do null checks and add items again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's not the property itself that's throwing the `NullReferenceException`, it's the act of trying to access the properties off of your class. I think your reference to the SPItem is no longer valid. Whatever mechanism you're using to cache it is returning null instead of an instance of SPItem, hence the `NullReferenceException`:

```
SPItem item = Cache.GetObject("MySPItem"); // <-- this is probably returning null
item.Name; // since item is null, trying to access the Name property would throw a NullReferenceException
```

Comment: Interesting. I can't figure out why it is losing the reference though.